# Generate dynamic robots.txt and also sitemap.xml in my Nuxt app or Vue app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, sitemap, robots.txt

What I'm trying to do here is to make nuxt.js or vue.js generate a robots.txt and sitemap.xml that can be pulish the data that inside each file from an external api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Nuxt, you can use these 2 modules to generate dynamically yours `robots.txt` and `sitemap.xml`

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/robots
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/sitemap

Comment: in the @nuxtjs/sitemap module what if I need the context object that is in nuxt or the "req" object to get the header can I do that in @nuxtjs/sitemap.
The reason of that is I have a saas product and I want every thing to dynamic by the domain, even the sitemap

Comment: to get the req object inside the "@nuxtjs/sitemap" package I had to get the module locally and  replace 
'await cache.routes.get('routes')'  with ' await options.routes(req) ' inside the middleware.js file to get the req object inside my routes because I have a Saas web app and want to the data that's are dynamically called by the domain so is that ok to do or not or there Is a better way

Comment: in SSR mode, if you don't set the "hostname" option in sitemap config, it will be automatically initialize from the `req` (see docs https://github.com/nuxt-community/sitemap-module#hostname-optional---string)

Comment: what if I want the `req` object in the routes object to call some API is this is possible

Comment: no, you cannot access to the "req" object because the module use a cache, so the req can be outdated. But you can make a simple async HTTP call (with axios or node-fetch). see eg. https://github.com/nuxt-community/sitemap-module#from-a-function-which-returns-a-promise

Comment: If you really need the "req" object, the better way for you is to create your own "serverMiddleware" with Nuxt, instead to use the sitemap module.